# Get current URL and find nav items matching part of it, then show submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a navigation menu which has submenus hidden by default. I want to display the submenu of the nav item that matches the current location, if I am on a page other than the home page.

I can find out the current pathname:

```
var currentUrl = (window.location.pathname);
```

I know how to scan href parameters:

```
$('ul.see li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]');
```

to get the submenu first directory.

How can I navigate through the nav items and add a class to a parent li item?

My menu markup is as follows:

```
<ul id="mainNavigation">
        <li class="hasKids"><a href="javascript:void(0)">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/about/the-salon">The Salon</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about/our-story">Our Story</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about/joe-mills">Joe Mills</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about/stylists">Stylists</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/about/products">Products</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="hasKids"><a href="javascript:void(0)">Services</a>
            <ul >
                <li><a href="/services/colour">Colour</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/services/cutting-&amp;-styling">Cutting &amp; Styling</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/services/waving-&amp;-straightening">Waving &amp; Straightening</a>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/services/treatments">Treatments</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

So as you see if I am /services/colour, I would like to show the services submenu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Q: How can I navigate through the nav items and add a class to a parent li item?

Assuming you are AT your anchor tag with:

```
var $a = $('ul.see li a[href^="/' + location.pathname.split("/")[1] + '"]');
```

Then, you can use the .closest() method to get to the closest LI

```
$a.closest('li')
```

Then, add the class you desire...and then navigate up to it's .closest('ul') if you need to add a class there, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your help Kevin, I got it sorted, but this looks like a legit solution